# Is there any of finding out the different contents of a json object?

Tags: android, json

Is there a way to determine what the different contents of a json object are?

Whether it contains json arrays in it? And if so is are there any json objects in that json array?

Comment: what type of other way you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course you can do that.
Take a look at the `JSONObject` reference:

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

You can use `keys()` iterator to discover which elements are available inside current node.

You can then use `instanceof` operator to check if some node is `JSONArray` or `String` or something else.

Comment: this is just brings back one object, when there is two objects and a an array

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void analyzeJSON(String jsonString) {
    JSONTokener tok = new JSONTokener(jsonString);
    while(tok.more()) {
        try {
            Object item = tok.nextValue();
            if (item instanceof JSONObject) {
                // JSON Object
                analyzeJSON(item.toString());
            } else if (item instanceof JSONArray) {
                // JSON Array
                JSONArray array = (JSONArray) item;
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    Object subItem = array.get(i);
                    if (subItem instanceof JSONObject) {
                        // JSON Object
                        analyzeJSON(item.toString());
                    } else if (subItem instanceof JSONArray) {
                        // JSON Array inside array
                    } else {
                        // Something
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this only returns the actual json object not anything inside it.

Comment: You can write this function recursively and get the items out of it.

Comment: can you give me a small example on how to do that aswin, thanks

Comment: @user: I think that you should learn basic programming concepts. Aswin wrote you complete example, if you do not understand that then you surely want understand recursion.

Comment: Dusan the example he wrote looks like to me a recursion, that's why I asked if I could have another example. An iterator did the trick inside a for loop. Thanks to any one who helped.